# When reading claims from JWT, I get the wrong encoding

Tags: c#, jwt

I have a program that catches webhooks. For starters, I just want to read their content.

I receive a JWT whose body is encrypted by RS256.

There is a public key for validation.

For some reason, in the first two claims the Cyrillic alphabet is deciphered incorrectly. But the following ones are correct.

Code for token read:

```
public void test(){
using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body))
                {
                    var body = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

                    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
                    rsa.ImportParameters(
                        new RSAParameters()
                        {
                            Modulus = FromBase64Url("rwm77av7GIttq-JF1itEgLCGEZW_zz16RlUQVYlLbJtyRSu61fCec_rroP6PxjXU2uLzUOaGaLgAPeUZAJrGuVp9nryKgbZceHckdHDYgJd9TsdJ1MYUsXaOb9joN9vmsCscBx1lwSlFQyNQsHUsrjuDk-opf6RCuazRQ9gkoDCX70HV8WBMFoVm-YWQKJHZEaIQxg_DU4gMFyKRkDGKsYKA0POL-UgWA1qkg6nHY5BOMKaqxbc5ky87muWB5nNk4mfmsckyFv9j1gBiXLKekA_y4UwG2o1pbOLpJS3bP_c95rm4M9ZBmGXqfOQhbjz8z-s9C11i-jmOQ2ByohS-ST3E5sqBzIsxxrxyQDTw--bZNhzpbciyYW4GfkkqyeYoOPd_84jPTBDKQXssvj8ZOj2XboS77tvEO1n1WlwUzh8HPCJod5_fEgSXuozpJtOggXBv0C2ps7yXlDZf-7Jar0UYc_NJEHJF-xShlqd6Q3sVL02PhSCM-ibn9DN9BKmD"),
                            Exponent = FromBase64Url("AQAB")
                        });
                    var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        RequireExpirationTime = true,
                        RequireSignedTokens = true,
                        ValidateAudience = false,
                        ValidateIssuer = false,
                        ValidateLifetime = false,
                        IssuerSigningKey = new RsaSecurityKey(rsa)
                    };

                    SecurityToken validatedSecurityToken;
                    var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                    handler.ValidateToken(body, validationParameters, out validatedSecurityToken);
                    JwtSecurityToken? validatedJwt = validatedSecurityToken as JwtSecurityToken;

                    if (validatedJwt != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var claim in validatedJwt.Claims.ToList())
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(claim.Value);
                        }
                        return Ok();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return BadRequest("Invalid token");
                    }
                }
}

static byte[] FromBase64Url(string base64Url)
        {
            string padded = base64Url.Length % 4 == 0
                ? base64Url : base64Url + "====".Substring(base64Url.Length % 4);
            string base64 = padded.Replace("_", "/")
                                  .Replace("-", "+");
            return Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
        }
```

Console messages:

```
SidePayer: {"bankCode": "000000000", "bankName": "\u041e\u041e\u041e \"\u0411\u0410\u041d\u041a \u0422\u041e\u0427\u041a\u0410\"", "bankCorrespondentAccount": "00000000000000000000", "account": "00000000000000000000", "name": "\u0418\u041f \u0422\u0435\u0441\u0442", "amount": "40.0", "currency": "RUB", "inn": "0000000000", "kpp": "0000000000"}
SideRecipient: {"bankCode": "000000000", "bankName": "\u041e\u041e\u041e \"\u0411\u0410\u041d\u041a \u0422\u041e\u0427\u041a\u0410\"", "bankCorrespondentAccount": "00000000000000000000", "account": "00000000000000000000", "name": "\u0418\u041f \u0422\u0435\u0441\u0442", "amount": "40.0", "currency": "RUB", "inn": "0000000000", "kpp": "0000000000"}
purpose: Тестовое назначение платежа
documentNumber: 00000
date: 2018-10-01
```

I tried the code above, but I get what you see.

SidePayer and SideRecipient contain \u.

purpose correctly displays the Cyrillic alphabet.

Comment: sorry, if its sounds bad... i really dont know what i need to do with this symbols :(

Comment: *a JWT whose body is encrypted by RS256* - No, you have a token that was signed with the RS256 signature algorithm and verify it with the public key. The data in this kind of token is not encrypted.

Comment: @jps okey, i understand. but why i have a problem with unicode symbols? 
Is this just my problem that needs to be solved using the method I wrote in the answer? or is there some other way out?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: This helped me:

```
Console.WriteLine(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape(claim.ToString()));
```

But I feel like I'm doing something wrong. Perhaps my approach is wrong. If you have anything to help you with, I'd be happy to listen!